# Filter items based on data attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of jQuery items found using

```
var groupedItems = $('div[data-group-id="'+groupId+'"]');
```

Each grouped item has a propery called

```
data-info={"isAvailable":"true","isValid":"false"}
```

from the groupedItem I want to filterOut only which has property isAvailable=true.

How can I filter based on data attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter jQuery collection and where you can use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to get the property.

```
var groupedItems = $('div[data-group-id="' + groupId + '"]');

var res = groupedItems.filter(function() {
  // since property value starts with {, the data method
  // would parse if it's a valid JSON. So simply get the
  // property from the object and compare
  return $(this).data('info').isAvailable == 'true';
})
```

Comment: has to be return $(this).dataObject('info').isAvailable

Comment: @hilda_sonica_vish : since value is string you need to compare

Comment: @hilda_sonica_vish : or you need to update the json with boolean instead of string `data-info='{"isAvailable": true,"isValid":"false"}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to filter `groupedItems` which have `isAvailable` set to `true` inside `info` data attribute. Access data attribute using `data()`.

```js
var groupId = 1;
var groupedItems = $('div[data-group-id="'+groupId+'"]');
var info = groupedItems.filter(function(){ 
  return $(this).data('info').isAvailable == 'true';
});
console.log(info);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-group-id=1 data-info={"isAvailable":"true","isValid":"false"}>foo</div>
```